# Save Google map to jpeg using PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

Is it even possible? I am implementing an export to pdf functionality for a pile of data, one of which is a Google map with a marker.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

you just need the url and the google api returns the google maps excerpt as a png file

Comment: HI, are there any options with google V3 apis, & any other alternative options than that ?

Comment: If there are initially 4 locations on a map and the user has zoomed in and might be dragged the map also so that only one location (marker) is currently visible, then how shall that map be converted to google staticmap and saved it as an image ?